# what changes needs to done in settings o IE to see drop down list of web application developed in .net?

Tags: .net, internet-explorer

I have a web application developed in .Net but when I run application I need to change some settings in IE to see the drop down list otherwise it doesn't show the drop down. I need to see drop down list without changing any settings.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't determine your current problem from your description. Is it possible that css style affects it? What options did you set to make it work? If possible, please provide a simple sample code and describe how to set IE options.

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved by adding css code to open the drop list.